# Append row between two rows

Tags: jquery

Help!! for the dynamic descending order tr feilds using Jquery Ajax. I have a table structure like this

```
<tr data-date="2015-01-30">
  <td class="col-lg-2">2015-01-30</td>
  <td class="col-lg-4">asdf sdaf </td>
</tr>
<tr data-date="2015-01-14">
  <td class="col-lg-2">2015-01-14</td>
  <td class="col-lg-4">asdf sdaf </td>
</tr>
```

Now i want to insert the row between this two rows i.e using the tr attribute called **data-date** if the new row's date attrib to be inserted is greater then the first one then it should be appended at the very top and if its between existed two rows then it should be appended after the greatest row and before the smallest row having smaller date attrib

for eg: i want to insert

```
<tr data-date="2015-01-16">
      <td class="col-lg-2">2015-01-30</td>
      <td class="col-lg-4">asdf sdaf </td>
    </tr>
```

between this two rows using jquery by checking where to append at the top, bottom or between two rows using the **data-date** attrib

Comment: `date` is not a valid html attribute. If you want to use custom attributes I suggest the `data-*`-attributes ([`data-date`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `.attr()` method to get the value of `date` attribute.
Then you must check this value and insert in the right place your `<tr>` but you need to have an `id` on any `<tr>`

Use `id` attribute = `date` attribute.

Use this examle, works for me: (copy and paste, save as .html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date_list = []; //create an array will contains all <tr> dates
    $("tr").each(function() {
        tr_date = $(this).attr("date"); //get data value of <tr>
        date_list.push(tr_date); //put date in array
    });
    var your_date = "2015-1-4";

    var big_to_small = false;  //Flag value set false = your <tr> are from small to big
    $("table").after(big_to_small);
    //Check the case if your <tr> are from big to small
    if (date_list[0] > date_list[date_list.length-1]){
        big_to_small=true;    //Set Flag value to true = your <tr> are from big to small
    }

    //Case 1: <tr> from big to small
    if (big_to_small){
        date_list = date_list.sort(); //Sort array
        date_list = date_list.reverse(); //Reverse array from big to small
        $.each(date_list, function(index ,value){
            //Insert <tr> up on top (of biggest date) or middle
            if (your_date > value){
                $("#"+value).before("<tr id='"+your_date+"' date='"+your_date+"'> <td>"+your_date+"</td><td>asdf sdaf </td></tr> ");
                return false;
            }
            //Insert <tr> down the smallest date
            if (your_date < date_list[date_list.length-1]){
                $("#"+date_list[date_list.length-1]).after("<tr id='"+your_date+"' date='"+your_date+"'> <td>"+your_date+"</td><td>asdf sdaf </td></tr>");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //Case 2: <tr> from small to big
    else{
    date_list = date_list.sort(); //Sort array
    $.each(date_list, function(index ,value){
            //Insert <tr> up on top (of smallest date) or middle
            if (your_date < value){
                $("#"+value).before("<tr id='"+your_date+"' date='"+your_date+"'> <td>"+your_date+"</td><td>asdf sdaf </td></tr> ");
                return false;
            }
            //Insert <tr> down the bigger date
            if (your_date > date_list[date_list.length-1]){
                $("#"+date_list[date_list.length-1]).after("<tr id='"+your_date+"' date='"+your_date+"'> <td>"+your_date+"</td><td>asdf sdaf </td></tr>");
                return false;
            }
        });
        }
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr id="2015-1-1" date="2015-1-1">
      <td class="col-lg-2">2015-1-1</td>
      <td class="col-lg-4">asdf sdaf </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2015-1-3" date="2015-1-3">
      <td class="col-lg-2">2015-1-3</td>
      <td class="col-lg-4">asdf sdaf </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2015-1-5" date="2015-1-5">
      <td class="col-lg-2">2015-1-5</td>
      <td class="col-lg-4">asdf sdaf </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Test yourself output! :D

Try also to change `<tr>` order in table from 2015-1-5 ... to 2015-1-1.

This code works only on ordered `<tr>` (any order).

Try to change value in var `your_date` to see the difference!

Comment: Last update works for date value like 2015-01-31 (biggest), 2015-01-16 (middle), 2015-01-13 (lowest).

Comment: this works great but the row is checked ony with the first element of the date array ie> 
if array contain 2015-1-1, 2015-1-4, and 2015-1-5 and i try to insert the 2015-1-6 then it insert between 2015-1-1 and 2015-1-5 not avove the 5

Comment: I started from the base that your `<tr>` are ordered from bigger date to smaller. Code works for this case. I edited the code with a solution that seems to works, in both case.

Comment: Note that this code will worl only on ordered `<tr>` (any order). If you have unordered `<tr>` maybe you can search for "How to order table elements jQuery".

Comment: You're welcome! If there are no other answers, you could accept this as the best. I really need to some reputation points. I'm new in the community :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use .after() :

```
var string = "<tr date="2015-01-14">
 <td class="col-lg-2">2015-01-14</td>
 <td class="col-lg-4">asdf sdaf</td>
</tr>";

$(tr[date='2015-01-30']).after(string);
```

Comment: but how to check if it is greaer or in between the rows in the document

Comment: If you mean a kind of date sorting, you better do it before, something like '$('tr').each(function(){ date comparaison here });' , it was your question ?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to assess whether the new tr predates your already existing trs and add if not? Sure :)

```
var example="2015-01-20";
$('tr[data]').each(function(){
    if(example>=$(this).attr("data")){
    $(this).before("<tr data='"+example+"'><to class='col-lg-2'>"+example+"</td></tr>");
    }
});
if($("tr[data='"+example+"']").length==0) $("tr:last-child[data]","table#yourTableName").after("<tr data='"+example+"'><td class='col-lg-2'>"+example+"</td></tr>");
```

Sorry if it's odd or whatever. Using my phone :d